# How to send/write Azure Static web form data to azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-connection, azure-blob-storage

Forgive my ignorance but I am at a stand still.

I created a data entry html form and parked it into an azure blob storage as a static website. I configured a custom domain and everything. Now my biggest problem is how to send the user data over to my azure sql database. I have been researching for nearly two days and everything points to creating web app. is there a way to send user input from the static web form stored in the blob directly to my azure sql db table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I can tell you clearly that using static website in blob storage does not support back-end server code. For more detail, you can see [the offical  document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jason, I guess I will just go ahead and create a web app.